# create a 3d content gallery site like this http://digital-deadly-sins.theguardian.com/#/Grida

Tags: gallery

how to create a 3d content gallery site like this  http://digital-deadly-sins.theguardian.com/#/Grida with out using flash. any jquery plugin or themes available

Answer (score 0):

See comments on the begining of file below:

http://digital-deadly-sins.theguardian.com/js/main.js

There is list of used scripts. Nice new knowledge ;-)

Kind regards,
A.